# how to change url in asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create search option in my ASP.net application to check Doctor details based on Location. If I try the below code, only home page is showing. `http:www.example.com/doctordetails.aspx?ID=1/DoctorName=IVIN`.

I want the URL to be changed as per location. Example expected URL: `http://www.example.com/doctordetails/chennai/doctors/saidapet`

I'm new to this technology.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                   <div class="tg-view tg-grid-view">
                                <div class="row">

                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <article class="tg-doctor-profile">
                                            <div class="tg-box">
                                       <figure class="tg-docprofile-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/doctors/img-13.jpg" alt="image description"></a></figure>
                                                    <span class="tg-featuredicon"><em class="fa fa-bolt"></em></span>
                                                <div class="tg-docprofile-content">
                                                    <div class="tg-heading-border tg-small">
                                                        <h3><a href="<%# String.Format("doctordetails.aspx?ID={0}/DoctorName={1}", Eval("DoctorID"),Eval("DoctorName"))   %>"><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DoctorName") %>' /></a></h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tg-description">
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <ul class="tg-doccontactinfo">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                                            <address><asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocAddress1") %>' /></address>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                                            <span><asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mobile") %>' /></address></span>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                                            <a ><asp:Label ID="lblmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' /></a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
                                                            <span>+44 235 856843</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                    </article>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Little bit unclear that what you are asking, Could you please be clear about your actual requirements?

Comment: i want like this url https://www.practo.com/chennai/doctors/saidapet @un-lucky

Comment: Use & to specify multiple query strings. Example: `ID=1&DoctorName=IVIN`

Comment: I'm new to this technology. Please help me sir what can i do ?@Ghasan

Comment: I want the URL to be changed as per location.Example Live Url https://www.practo.com/chennai/doctors/saidapet......

Comment: getting information from databse

Comment: How you are planning to locate those values if URL changes? I think you have to use multiple values in querystring

Comment: any samples code like this ?@un-lucky

Answer (score 2):

Hope that you wanted to pass multiple params through query string and access those value in that particular form. if so you have to change the code like this:

```
<a href="<%# String.Format("doctordetails.aspx?loc={0}&ID={1}&DoctorName={2}", Eval("Location"),Eval("DoctorID"),Eval("DoctorName")) %>"></a>
```

And the code for accessing those values is:

```
Request.QueryString["Location"]; // Will give you the passed value for location
Request.QueryString["DoctorID"]; // Will give you the passed value for DoctorID
Request.QueryString["DoctorName"]; // Will give you the passed value for DoctorName
```

Comment: showing error System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Location'.   @un-lucky

Comment: Hope that you have `DoctorID` in the collection that you are used to bind the grid view, like wise include `Location` as well in the comllection

Comment: yes it's working  http://localhost:49247/doctordetails.aspx?loc=chennai&ID=1&DoctorName=IVIN   this url

Comment: but i want like this url http://localhost:49247/doctordetails.aspx?chennai/doctors/saidapet  @un-lucky

Comment: I think you ware misunderstand the meaning of URL

Comment: I think not possible, lets wait for others comments